# Migrating Apache Spark xml from 2.11 to 2.12 gives the below warning.How to use The xmlReader directly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, apache-spark-xml

Code:

```
val xmlDf: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("xml")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .xml(df.select("payload").map(x => x.getString(0)))
```

warning: method xml in class XmlDataFrameReader is deprecated (since 0.13.0): Use XmlReader directly
.xml(df.select("payload").map(x => x.getString(0)))

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read xml to df or read xml from a column to df (nested xml)?

please try either:

```
spark.read()
  .format("xml")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .load("books.xml");
```

or:

```
import com.databricks.spark.xml.functions.from_xml
import com.databricks.spark.xml.schema_of_xml
import spark.implicits._
val df = ... /// DataFrame with XML in column 'payload' 
val payloadSchema = schema_of_xml(df.select("payload").as[String])
val parsed = df.withColumn("parsed", from_xml($"payload", payloadSchema))
```

https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml
(Compatible with Spark 2.4.x and 3.x, with Scala 2.12.)